# After posting some data using httparty, how can I access the posted values in controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, httparty

I have done a posting using httparty.

E.g.

```
options={ 
  :foo => '123'
  :bar => 'second',
  :baz => 'last thing'
}

HTTParty.post("localhost/tests" , options)
```

How can I retrieve options parameters in my remote app controller: 
E.g.

```
#post /tests
def create
@k=options[:name]  -------> Here is my question, How can I access options[:name]?
```

I mean should I pass options as an argument of create method? Something like:

```
def create(options)
@k=options[:name]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay it worked for me finally. I should have retrieved each fields separately rather than as a whole. So happy! So now I have 2 rails app. just by wrapping fields separately and fetching them separately I was able to post and retrieve.